# How to serve a bundled js file with hashed name in Node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

I'm using Parcel to bundle my client code and everytime I run a production build it bundles the javascript code into a file with a hashed portion. Ex: `webrtc.27c30b71.js`.

At the moment, everytime I build my client code, I have to go into my server file and manually change the code to reflect the new generated hashed name.

```
const handleRequest = (request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse) => {
  // Render the single client html file for any request the HTTP server receives
  console.log('request received: ' + request.url);

  if(request.url === '/') {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('dist/index.html'));
  } else if(request.url === '/webrtc.27c30b71.js')) {   <----------
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('dist/webrtc.27c30b71.js'));   <-----------
  }
};
```

There has got to be a better way to go about this. How can I make it so that I don't have to manually modify my server code everytime I rebuild the client code?

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution, I have no idea if it would be considered best practice for dealing with this but it works and I need to move on to more important things.

```
const handleRequest = (request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse) => {
  // Render the single client html file for any request the HTTP server receives
  console.log('request received: ' + request.url);

  if(request.url === '/') {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('dist/index.html'));
  } else if(/(\/)(webrtc)(\.).*?(\.)(js)/.test(request.url as string)) { <----------
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    response.end(fs.readFileSync(`dist${request.url}`));                 <---------
  }
};
```

I have used a regex test to allow for any request where the path matches `/webrtc.[hash].js` and then I proceed to serve the file that matches the path requested.